# Global Style for GridSplitter that depends on its orientation

Tags: wpf, grid, styles, gridsplitter

I'd like to create a global style that would affect every "GridSplitter" of my app to change its cursor appearance when mouse is over.

This code works for vertical GridSplitter:

```
<Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
  <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWe"></Setter>
</Style>
```

But I don't know how to detect its orientation and set the Value to "SizeNs" when appropriate.
I do not want to have to change every GridSplitter code. I want one style that could apply for every Gridsplitter without having to set a resource key.

Any idea ?

For all of those who have a XamlParseException : 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '15' and line position '9'.

Ensure you have proper syntax for Cursor names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ResizeDirection` property in control template triggers and set appropriate cursor.

```
<Style TargetType="GridSplitter">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridSplitter">                        

                <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Rectangle>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ResizeDirection" Value="Columns">
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeNS"></Setter>                                
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ResizeDirection" Value="Rows">
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Hello Nitesh, thanks it works like a charm. How did you know that you had to add: <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Rectangle> to ensure to not get the  XamlParseException (System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension about the 'SizeWe' not found) ??? I really didn't find anything about it. Why does it required to remove the exception ???

Comment: Please use `SizeWE` instead of `SizeWe`. The XAML line of code you mentioned has nothing to do with this exception. The exception occurred because of a slight typing mistake.